# how do i create a virtual keyboard that can be used to insert values in different jtextfields

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to create a virtual keyboard that can insert values in a Jtextfield of another Jframe. The problem is that the data is overlapping when editing  other text fields. So, I tried renewing the object but it replaced the first Jtextfield value as well. what should i do with this, should i start from scratch or is there any other way? . Since, English is not my first language I am struggling to find the correct terminology to research the problem please enlighten me with your knowledge

```
import java.awt.*;     
import javax.swing.*;  



public class OnScreenKeyboard implements ActionListener {

JFrame keyboard;
static String keyboardKeys = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm.< ";
JButton[] keys = new JButton[39];
GridLayout gl;
FlowLayout fl;
Dimension buttondimension;
JPanel panel1, panel2;

JToggleButton capslock;
private String message = "";

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public OnScreenKeyboard() {
    buttondimension = new Dimension(45, 40);

    fl = new FlowLayout();

    capslock = new JToggleButton("capslock");

    panel1 = new JPanel(fl);
    panel2 = new JPanel(fl);

    char[] key = keyboardKeys.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
        keys[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(key[i]));
        keys[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        if (i == 38) {
            keys[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        } else {

            keys[i].setPreferredSize(buttondimension);
        }
        keys[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    keyboard = new JFrame("Keyboard");
    keyboard.setSize(720, 220);
    keyboard.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    keyboard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    keyboard.setResizable(false);

    Container content = keyboard.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(null);
    panel1.setBounds(1, 1, 500, 210);
    panel2.setBounds(510, 1, 200, 210);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        panel2.add(keys[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 10; i < 39; i++) {
        panel1.add(keys[i]);
    }

    panel1.add(capslock);

    content.add(panel1);
    content.add(panel2);

    capslock.addActionListener(this);

    keyboard.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new OnScreenKeyboard();

}

public void reset(){
    message = "";
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        if (e.getSource() == keys[i]) {
            setMessage(getMessage() + keys[i].getText());
            break;
        }
    }

    if (e.getSource() == capslock) {
        if (capslock.isSelected()) {
            for (int i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
                keys[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                keys[i].setText(keys[i].getText().toUpperCase());

            }
        } else if (!capslock.isSelected()) {
            for (int i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
                keys[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
               keys[i].setText(keys[i].getText().toLowerCase());

            }
        }
    }

    setMessage(getMessage());

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getMessage());

}

}
```

this is the frame I am trying to put my values from the keyboard in

```
public class LoginScreen implements ActionListener, FocusListener {

JFrame frame;
Container content;
FlowLayout fl;

JTextField txtusername, txtpassword;
JLabel lblusername, lblpassword;

JPanel panel1, panel2;

JButton keyboard, signup, signin;
OnScreenKeyboard kyb;
Dimension text;

private void init() {
    text =new Dimension(100, 30);

    fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    lblusername = new JLabel("enter username");
    lblpassword = new JLabel("enter password");
    txtusername = new JTextField();
    txtpassword = new JPasswordField();

    keyboard = new JButton("keyboard");
    signup = new JButton("signup");
    signin = new JButton("sign in");

    panel1 = new JPanel(fl);
    panel2 = new JPanel(fl);

    keyboard = new JButton("keyboard");

    txtusername.setPreferredSize(text);
    txtpassword.setPreferredSize(text);

    kyb = new OnScreenKeyboard();

}

public LoginScreen() {

    init();
    frame = new JFrame("BorderLayoutDemo");
    frame.setTitle("Registration Form");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    content = frame.getContentPane();

    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    panel1.add(lblusername);
    panel1.add(txtusername);
    panel1.add(lblpassword);
    panel1.add(txtpassword);

    panel2.add(signup);
    panel2.add(signin);
    panel2.add(keyboard);

    content.add(panel1);
    content.add(panel2);
    keyboard.addActionListener(this);

    txtusername.addFocusListener(this);
    txtpassword.addFocusListener(this);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LoginScreen();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (!kyb.keyboard.isVisible()) {
        if (e.getSource() == keyboard) {
            kyb = new OnScreenKeyboard();
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
   if(txtusername == e.getSource()){
       txtusername.setText(kyb.getMessage());

   }else if(txtpassword == e.getSource()){

       kyb.reset();
       txtpassword.setText(kyb.getMessage());
   }
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's weird how/when the text is taken from the keyboard.

You use the LoginScreen both as actionListener on the keyboard and as focusListener on the 2 textfields.

The way you implemented it now is that you "type" something in on the keyboard and after that put the focus on 1 of the 2 fields. Only at the moment you click the text from the keyboard is fetched (kyb.getMessage()).

It's especially a problem on the password. If you click on the txtpassword field you first reset the kyb and then fetch the message (which you just reset so is empty).

What felt weird for me is that you don't have a way in the keyboard to notion that you are done typing. So the flow of only getting the message when the focus changes to one of the text fields is wrong.

What I would do is create a new kind of KeyboardListener. This listener is put on the txtusername OR txtpassword depending on who last took focus (so in the focusGained() you should change who is listening to the keyboard).

Then each time a key is "typed" you should notify the listener of the letter and then the txtusername/txtpassword (whichever is listening at that time) should add that letter to its text.

This means that the keyboard itself doesn't need to remember any text. It just figures out which key was pressed and then sends the corresponding letter to the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `TextAction` as your `ActionListener`. The `TextAction` has a method `getFocusedComponent()` which will return the last text component to have focus.

Then in the can add the character to the text field. So the basic code in the `actionPerformed(...)` method of the `TextAction` might be something like:

```
JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
component.replaceSelection( the character to add );
```